# Enabled root password and have System Policy and sudo problem

Tags: security, password, cpufreq

**I enabled the root password a while back.** But not three days ago. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with latest updates. My laptop is Vostro 3500

For about three day ago, I saw the symptoms. And those are, 
When I use sudo on terminal, it doesn't ask for my password. It just do it.
Eg. sudo apt-get update just execute.

I use cpufreq utilities and their unity indicator to change cpu scaling. It didn't ask for my password. But, now window appear to ask my password when I want to change cpu scaling mode. (ondemand to power save etc. ) (password windows is same as when I open synaptic package manager.).

Answer (score 1):

You seem you have made a change for the /etc/sudeors file.if you wanna restore defaults just get it from the source and then replace your file with it. or else you can just edit your file and obligate sudo to ask for password. when you open your file move to the line where `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` if there is something wrong and you cant find this line so edit line that contains %sudo and paste this. Also you can make something else just add the following `yourUserNAme ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL`